# Pyspark - Columns from .xlsx with first value/header empty not being read

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

When reading .xlsx format, those columns with first value (if header = false) or title (if header = true) empty are omitted and not read.

Tried unsucessfully by tuning several option parameters (header, inferSchema, treatEmptyValuesAsNulls) with all combinations possible.

**Original file:**

| DL |  | Store |  |  | MSC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |
| 1 | REAL,- | 4330942080010 | 8001 | REAL MUTTERSTADT | 101 |

**Result:**

| DL | Store | MSC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |
| 1 | 4330942080010 | 101 |

#### Steps To Reproduce

```
#tested with all parameters combinations
data = (spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                .option("dataAddress", "'data'!A1")
                .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
                .option("Header", "true")
                .option("inferSchema", "false") 
                .load("empty_column_name_example.xlsx")
display(data)
```